# NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object - stumped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've searched online here for similar questions, but none seem to fit my specific problem.  If I create the user in the console and save, I'm told they're valid.  When I create my users in the local environment, however, and ask the console if they're valid, I'm told they're false and receive the following error message:

```
     NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
from (irb):4
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/RichardEssig/Desktop/coding/freedom/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:180:in `block in serve'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `fork'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/RichardEssig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

Here is my Users Model code:

```
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, :industry, :company, :title, :street, :state, :city, :zip, presence: true
  validates :phone, presence: true, length: { maximum: 11 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
   validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    has_secure_password
    validate :password_complexity
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

    def password_complexity
    return unless password.present?
    unless password =~ /[a-z]/ && password =~ /[A-Z]/ && password =~ /[\d]/
    errors.add :password, "must include at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, and one digit"

  end
end
end
```

Any ideas why my users are not valid?  They show up in the local environment and I can update, and destroy them.  So confused here.

I'm saving new users in the views/users/new form which look as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">

       <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> </h2>

  <ul>
     <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
       <li><%= message %></li>
     <% end %>
     </ul>
   </div>
 <% end %>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

.
.
.

 <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Regarding the error message, I typed in the following code in the console after I I'm informed the user is false:

```
user.errors.full_messages
```

Comment: can you show how you are saving, as well as what you called when you get that error, also, where you called it?

Comment: It's not that a user object is not valid; rather, it's that the *variable* `user` cannot be found.

Comment: You are getting this error because wherever you are in your console you have not defined the user variable.  What exactly are you typing into your console and what is the return value of each statement.

Comment: thanks, everyone.  That makes sense.  I guess a better question to ask would be, why are my users showing up as false in the console, after I save them in my local test environment?